# Customising UISlider (without coding a custom one)

Tags: ios, interface, uislider

I want to have a UISlider with a uniform green colour (no gradients).

When I try to paint the uislider's track it appears to have a gradient even if I put the line:

slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

(Second slider in the image)

When I try to put an image coloured green (in the picture is blue but ignore it...) I am not able to round the corners of the layer:

slider.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

EDIT:

I ended up customizing it [UISlider custom images and thumb height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311996/uislider-custom-images-and-thumb-height)

Is it possible for me to achieve this without customising a the uislider?

[image]

Comment: Update your image with the rounded corners.

Comment: This is probably the best solution. I am going to try it asap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com) actually has a free tutorial about customizing `UIKit` components. See [User Interface Customization in iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6).

Note that although this tutorial is titled `in iOS 6`, the `appearance` proxy is available starting in iOS 5.0, so most of this tutorial is actually relevant for iOS 5.0+.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, the *gradient* you mentioned is actually an image that's overlaid on top of the tint color by default, and there doesn't appear to be an easy way (such as a `property`) to disable this.

As [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963) suggestions in the comments though, you can simply create and use an image with rounded corners to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do through interface build too.Choose whatever colors or images you want to use.
[image]

Comment: I have tried this solution before (second slider). The problem here is that the color is not uniform, it has a gradient above and I cannot remove it.

Comment: Then you can simply put your images in min image and max imgae

Comment: I also did that approach (first slider). My issue here is that I cannot apply the rounded corners to the track.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311996/uislider-custom-images-and-thumb-height/10329232#comment25350562_10329232

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

 Add this line after slider.layer.cornerRadius = 10

```
    slider.clipsToBounds = true
```